# Regular Expression for A-Z or 1-8

Tags: regex

What would the regular expression that matches the following requirements:
- Exactly one character in length
- Must be an upper-case letter OR a digit from 1-8

Answer (score 7):

You should read a [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

```
^[A-Z1-8]$
```

Comment: +1 For the RTFM, not for the answer; this question may set a record for the lamest regex question on SO to date.

Comment: That regex will match english letters only. If you try with non-english letters it will fail: `ÁÊ`

Comment: @RuiJarimba, sure! But the question explicitly asked for A to Z, and without knowing the regex flavor there is no general solution that works with Unicode. What about upper-case cyrillic letters? Should they be accepted, too? Or only modified Latin letters? I think for the scope of the question, the given regex is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[A-Z1-8]$/
```

Which variant of regular expression?

Comment: Those wrapping slashes are totally irrelevant to regular expressions; they are a language artefact.

Answer (score 1):

[A-Z1-8] is the way to test matching one character

Comment: In most regex implementations this will match as long as there is at least one of these characters inside, regardless of length.